# Google Apps Script does not save a spreadsheet before coping it

Tags: google-apps-script

The following code creates "new spreadsheet" and set "test" to `cell A1` and copies the spreadsheet to "copied spreadsheet".

But "test" of cell A1 is set only to "new spreadsheet" but "copied spreadsheet".
Is there some save() method to save a spreadsheet modified by gas?

```
  // create spreadsheet named "new spreadsheet"
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create('new spreadsheet');

  const sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

  // set "test" to cell A1
  sheet.getRange(1, 1).setValue('test');
  
  // copy "new spreadsheet" to "copied spreadsheet"
  // *but cell A1 of "copied spreadsheet" is unexpectedly blank.
  DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheet.getId()).makeCopy('copied spreadsheet');
```

What I really want to do is to modify spreadsheet cells and send it as an attachment file of a mail.
But the same issue I wrote above happens. The modifications to cells are not applied to the attached spreadsheet.

```
  GmailApp.sendEmail(
    to,
    subject,
    body,
    {
      // *modifications to the spreadsheet by gas are ignored
      attachments: spreadsheet,
    }
  );
```

Comment: Please put `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` before the line of `DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheet.getId()).makeCopy('copied spreadsheet')` and test it again.

Comment: Thank you! SpreadsheetApp.flush() fixed the issue.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. There are several duplicated questions of this situation. So I flagged this as a duplicated question.

Comment: Thank you for flagging. The already answered question was difficult to find for me. The already answered question is exactly very similar to my situation.